# Microsoft Azure: Advanced Management Portal link is disabled

Tags: azure, dns, azureportal

I purchased a domain at the Azure portal.
When I used the Azure portal to the advanced management portal link is disabled.
The domain is due for renewal (And I want to transfer it also update DNS records at the hosting space provider)
I am the admin of the subscription.

Question: Why is the Advanced Management portal link disabled? What can I do about it?

[image]

Comment: Hello @Ziaullah Khan, can you try opening this link in the same window of the browser in which portal is opened `https://web1.appsvcux.ext.azure.com/api/Websites/GetDomainsSSORequest` as a work around.

Comment: Got thought. It didn't work. Probably the Advanced Management Portal is a post request. This link here failed with error 500 (I checked in developer toolbar) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Advanced Management Portal` link is disabled as the Microsoft team is working on a new user interface.

Right Click on the disabled `Advanced Management Portal` Link and Click '`Open In New Tab`'
The new window has the advanced management portal controls and then you can follow the regular flow.